# Eject sound when turn off monitor or went to sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep, power-management, dvi

## Specs

- Ryzen2600
- Rx570
- ITX ROG ASUS b350
- Windows 10 1809 (17763.316)

The monitor is Zowie 2411L via dual-link DVI. The secondary monitor is a random LG monitor. Both being 24inch and 1080p.

If the monitor goes to sleep according to the power plan, my pc will make an eject sound. It is not like the pc is not reacting to this, the pc acts as if the graphics are restarted. For example, if I have a game running, turn off my monitor manually, it will make eject sound and then crash the game. Also, all the window will rearrange themselves.

I also have the second monitor it is normal LG I don't even know the model, very old one via HDMI. and it acts like what we expected for many years, nothing, the pc doesn't know if it is on or off, so if I turn back on the LG, everything is still there.

This is a very annoying problem because I never shut off my pc, because of work. This problem crashes my software. Right now my solution is never let monitor go sleep. Which to me is a waste and it is very bright during the night.

I tried to use USBlog to see if there is anything else, but no, it is the monitor, I also use HDMI to hook up the Zowie and pc, same problem.

It is very weird, it only started happening when I switched to AMD rx570 card, I used to have 1070gtx.

Comment: You could try to completely uninstall (I believe there's some utility for this from both AMD and Nvidia) and reinstall back video drivers.

Comment: Does the screen have a USB hub built in to it?

Comment: @Burgi no, it doesnt have. but it has an auido jack out put. i guess its getting data from HDMI audio?  http://images.bit-tech.net/content_images/2016/12/benq-zowie-xl2411-review/xl2411-10b.jpg